# Laravel openssl_private_encrypt(): key param is not a valid private key

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, chef-infra, rsa

I am trying to connect to Chef API with Laravel using [PHP-Chef](http://github.com/jenssegers/php-chef). I have tried to set up my chef config with the data that I got from knife.rb in .chef folder. I have setup client and a key according to the instructions from [Knife.rb](http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html). But I get:

```
openssl_private_encrypt(): key param is not a valid private key
```

And in my controller when I do `dd($this->key)` I get null in return. This is my controller:

```
protected $server;
protected $client;
protected $key;
protected $version;

public function ___construct()
{
  $this->server = config('chef.server');
  $this->client = config('chef.client');
  $this->key = config('chef.key');
  $this->version = config('chef.version');
}

/**
 * Get all dns records
 */
public function index()
{
  dd($this->key);
  $chef = new Chef($this->server, $this->client, $this->key, $this->version);

  // API request
  $response = $chef->get('/');
  dd($response);
}
```

And this is my config chef.php

```
return [
'server'    => 'https://172.16.0.227:443/organizations/myOrganizationsName',
'client'    => 'chef-validator',
'key'       => '/Users/myName/.chef/ORGANIZATION-validator.pem',
'version'   => '12.7.0',
"enterprise" => false
];
```

Comment: I know little of PHP, and you seem to have sanitized your data, but are you 100% sure that the key file exists and is readable by PHP?

Comment: Actually the path was wrong, since I am having my projects on homestead, I had to copy the folder to the root project directory and change the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying this down to answer since I guess it was right, but this smells like a bad key path or file permissions such that PHP couldn't read the key data.